# Find position of specific data and assign new value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, crystal-reports

We have a clunky data set that I'd like to make into a view. I created a stored proc to take care of this, but I cannot use it from within Crystal Reports like I intended.

Here's an example of the data set in question.

```
SalesOrder    Item     Qty    Comment                  SalesOrderLineNo
12345         4321     1                               1
12345         4322     3                               2
12345         4312     5                               3
12345                                                  4
12345                                                  5
12345                         -----Payment Info-----   9
12345                         Payment:          $100  10
12345                         Invoiced:          $90  11
12345                         Date          10-12-16  12
12345                                                 13
12346         4344     1                               1
12346         4376     3                               2
12346         4329     5                               3
12346         4567     1                               4
12346                                                  5
12346                                                  6
12346                        Free Freight              7
12346                                                  8
12346                         -----Deposit Info-----   9
12346                         Deposit:          $400  10
12346                         Remaining:        $190  11
12346                         Date          10-10-16  12
12348         4390     1                               1
12348                         Credit Card on File      2
12348                         Call Bill on Delivery    3
12348                         ----Shipping Notes----   4
12348                         Address                  5                   
12348                         14356 21st ST            6                   
12348                         City, State Zip          7
```

What I want to do is write a query that will find the `SalesOrderLineNo` that contains the text for either "-----Deposit Info-----" or "-----Payment Info-----" and assign it a value. The data I need to hide will start at the `SalesOrderLineNo` and end at `SalesOrderLineNo + 3`, meaning there will always be 4 `Comment` lines that will need to be hidden. That should never change.

Here is the proc I created for a single sales order that works perfectly. It hides all of the lines that I need it to. Unfortunately

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[uspS_SRS_RemovePaymentDetailsBOL] @SalesOrder INT
AS

DECLARE 
@Start AS INT

SET @Start = (SELECT SalesOrderLineNo
            FROM SorDetail
           WHERE SalesOrder = @SalesOrder
             AND Comment =  '-----Payment Info-----')

 SELECT SalesOrder
      , Comment
      , Item
      , Qty
      , SalesOrderLineNo
   FROM SalesOrderDetail
  WHERE CAST(SalesOrder AS INT) = @SalesOrder
    AND SalesOrderLine NOT BETWEEN @Start AND @Start + 3
    AND NComment != ''
```

Here's where I'm stuck. How can I assign a value of 1 to those specific comment lines of "-----Payment Info-----" and "-----Deposit Info-----' knowing the `SalesOrderLineNo` will never be consistent or the same for each sales order? See data example below.

```
SalesOrder    Item     Qty    Comment                  SalesOrderLineNo    NewAssignedValue
12345         4321     1                               1                   0
12345         4322     3                               2                   0
12345         4312     5                               3                   0
12345                                                  4                   0
12345                                                  5                   0
12345                         -----Payment Info-----   9                   1
12345                         Payment:          $100  10                   1
12345                         Invoiced:          $90  11                   1
12345                         Date          10-12-16  12                   1
12345                                                 13                   0
12346         4344     1                               1                   0
12346         4376     3                               2                   0
12346         4329     5                               3                   0
12346         4567     1                               4                   0
12346                                                  5                   0
12346                                                  6                   0
12346                        Free Freight              7                   0
12346                                                  8                   0
12346                         -----Deposit Info-----   9                   1
12346                         Deposit:          $400  10                   1
12346                         Remaining:        $190  11                   1
12346                         Date          10-10-16  12                   1
12348         4390     1                               1                   0
12348                         Credit Card on File      2                   0
12348                         Call Bill on Delivery    3                   0
12348                         ----Shipping Notes----   4                   0
12348                         Address                  5                   0
12348                         14356 21st ST            6                   0
12348                         City, State Zip          7                   0
```

EDIT: I've added more detail to the data sets

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.*
      ,NewAssignedValue = case when B.SalesOrder is null then 0 else 1 end
  From YourTable A
  Left Join (
             Select SalesOrder,SalesOrderLineNo
              From  YourTable 
              Where Comment in ('-----Payment Info-----','-----Deposit Info-----')
             ) B on A.SalesOrder=B.SalesOrder and A.SalesOrderLineNo between B.SalesOrderLineNo and B.SalesOrderLineNo+3
 Order by SalesOrder,SalesOrderLineNo
```

Either One Returns

[image]

Comment: John, appreciate the solution. I might've missed something in my initial question. I've added in some new information that might make your solution not work. I'll test and verify

Comment: Also, my first set of data in my question was misleading. I'm not trying to flag comments, I'm trying to assign a value to line numbers containing info about depost and payment. There will be other comments in random areas

Comment: @jdidsQAA  Updated answer - removed 1st query 2nd still worked